# How to prove that $n \choose r$ = $\frac{n+1-r}{r}$ $n \choose r-1$ without using the factorial expansion of $n \choose r$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, combinatorial-proofs

How to prove that $n \choose r$ = $\frac{n+1-r}{r}$ $n \choose   r-1$ without using the factorial expansion of $n \choose r$.

Comment: The extreme brevity of you post invites confusion as to what, instead of "the factorial expansion", you would use to *define* the binomial coefficients.  Please include this essential set up to the problem in the body of your Question.

Answer (score 4):

The left-hand-side clearly counts the number of ways to choose $r$ objects out of $n$ total.

The right-hand-side counts the same, but its logic is the following:

- Pick $r-1$ objects first.
- From the remaining $n-(r-1)$ objects, pick one of them to fill the remaining empty spot.
- Recognize that for each choice of $r$ objects, this method has counted each a total of $r$ times, so divide by $r$ to account for the symmetry of the problem.

This gives a total of $\binom{n}{r-1}(n-(r-1))\cdot\frac{1}{r}=\frac{n+1-r}{r}\binom{n}{r-1}$ ways of selecting $r$ objects out of $n$ total.

By fundamental principles, if two expressions correctly count the number of outcomes of the same scenario, then they must be equal.

Comment: I didn't get point number (3). Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Supermario As we go through via multiplication principle, we ordinarily hope to count each outcome exactly once, however in this case had we applied multiplication principle for the first two steps, we have in fact counted each outcome a total of $r$ times.  (*e.g. having picked $\{a,b,c\},\{d\}$ gives the same outcome as $\{a,b,d\},\{c\}$ and $\{a,c,d\},\{b\}$ etc...*).  Since each was counted the same number of times, if we divide by the number of times each was counted it is as though we have counted each once only which is what we intended.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to see it if you write it as:

$$\binom{n}{r}r=\binom{n}{r-1}(n+1-r)$$

The left side counts the number of ways to select $r$ elements, then select one of those $r$.

The right side is the number of ways to select $r-1$ elements, and then select one more element from the $n-(r-1)=n-r+1$ remaining elements.

---

You can prove the theorem inductively on $n$, using $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$, the Pascal triangle identity.

I'll skip the case $n=1$.

If true for $n$, then for $r\geq 1$ we have:

$$\begin{align}r\binom{n+1}{r} &=r\binom{n}{r-1} + r\binom{n}{r}\\
&= r\binom{n}{r-1}+(n-r+1)\binom{n}{r-1}\tag{*}\\
&= (n+1)\binom{n}{r-1}
\end{align}$$

Where the substitution $(*)$ is allowed by the induction hypothesis.

On the other hand, if $r>1$, then:

$$\begin{align}(n+1-r+1)\binom{n+1}{r-1} 
&=(n+2-r)\binom{n}{r-1}+(n+2-r)\binom{n}{r-2}\\
&=(n+2-r)\binom{n}{r-1}+(r-1)\binom{n}{r-1}\tag{*}\\
&=(n+1)\binom{n}{r-1}
\end{align}$$

where again, the substitution is allowed by the induction hypothesis.

So the two values are equal. You have to deal with the care where $r=1$ separately.

So $$r\binom{n+1}{r}=((n+1)-r+1)\binom{n+1}{r-1}$$

and the induction is done.

Comment: Actually I was trying to prove this recursive formula that you are proving from the one I asked for. But first I needed to prove the one asked in the question.

Comment: Oh, I got the formula backwards. Misread. Fixed.

Comment: I actually like this explanation more than mine because it avoids the "divide to account for symmetry" argument which so many people seem to struggle with.  +1

Comment: Yes, always try to avoid division in counting arguments, unless absolutely necessary. :) @JMoravitz

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Wow! Excellent proof by double counting. Can we accomplish our task without using the fact that $n \choose r$ represents the number of ways of selecting $r$ objects out $n$? By using the fact that $n \choose r$ represents the $r+1$th term in the $n$th row of Pascal's triangle or some other fact.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> One possible approach is the introduction of a *Generating Function* 'technique'. Essentially, it just involves the identity
>   $\ds{\left.\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}{n \choose r}z^{r}
> \,\right\vert_{\ \verts{z}\ <\ 1}\ =\ \pars{1 + z}^{n} - 1}$. Hereafter, I'll develop this approach:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\color{#f00}{{n + 1 - r \over r}{n \choose r - 1}}z^{r} =
\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}{n - r \over r + 1}{n \choose r}z^{r + 1}
=
\pars{n + 1}z\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose r}{z^{r} \over r + 1} -
z\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose r}z^{r}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{n + 1}z\sum_{r = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose r}z^{r}\int_{0}^{1}t^{r}\,\dd t -
z\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{n + 1}z\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 + zt}^{n}\,\dd t - \pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} +
\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{n + 1}z\,{\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} - 1 \over \pars{n + 1}z} -
\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} + \pars{1 + z}^{n} = \pars{1 + z}^{n} - 1 =
\sum_{r = 1}^{\infty}\color{#f00}{n \choose r}z^{r}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer based upon the two binomial identities
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{r}&=\binom{n}{n-r}\tag{1}\\
\binom{n}{r}&=\binom{n-1}{r-1}\frac{n}{r}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We start with the right-hand side and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{n+1-r}{r}\binom{n}{r-1}&=\frac{n+1-r}{r}\binom{n}{n+1-r}\qquad &\rightarrow (1)\\
> &=\frac{n+1-r}{r}\cdot \frac{n}{n+1-r}\binom{n-1}{n-r}\qquad &\rightarrow (2)\\
> &=\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{n-r}\\
> &=\frac{n}{r}\binom{n-1}{r-1}&\qquad\rightarrow (1)\\
> &=\binom{n}{r}&\quad\rightarrow (2)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the bipartite graph where vertices on the left side are the $k$-sets and vertices on the other are $(k+1)$-sets and we connect two if one contains the other.

Since vertices on the left side have degree $n-k$ and vertices on the right have degree $k+1$ we get the desired equality when counting the number of edges.

Answer (score 0):

- $\dbinom nr\dbinom r 1$ **counts all the distinct ways to** select $r$ from $n$ items and then $1$ from those $r$. Thus **produce sets of size $r-1$, $1$, and $n-r$ items from a set of $n$ items.**
- $\dbinom{n}{r-1}\dbinom {n-r+1}1$ **all the distinct ways to** select $r-1$ from $n$ items and then $1$ from the remaining $n-r+1$ items. Thus **produce sets of size $1$, $r-1$, and $n-r$ items from a set of $n$ items.**
- These counts must be equal.